# Perl : what is my ($self, $firstName)

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl language.

Can anyone explain the following subroutine, what is the difference between `my ($self, $firstName)` and `$self->{_firstName}`, it would be helpful if you can explain by relating it with Java:

```
sub setFirstName {
    my ( $self, $firstName ) = @_;
    $self->{_firstName} = $firstName if defined($firstName);
    return $self->{_firstName};
}
```

Comment: `$self` is `this`, but perl unlike java requires explicit assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my ( $self, $firstName ) =` defines two variables and assigns them values from the *list* on the right hand side of the assignment operator.

`$self->{_firstName} =` treats the value of `$self` as a hashref and assigns a value to the `_firstName` key of the hash that it references.

Comment: It might help to explain that `setFirstName` is a method and `$self` is the object invoking the method.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common way to define an accessor (getter and setter at the same time). Its name is a bit misleading, as it's not a setter only.

It corresponds to something like

```
class Whatever {

    private String firstName;

    public String setFirstName (String newName) {
        firstName = newName;
        return firstName;
    }

    public String setFirstName () {
        return firstName;
    }

}
```

To set the firstname, use

```
$object->setFirstName("name");
```

To get it, use no arguments:

```
my $name = $object->setFirstName;
```